# Create flexible property names in the searchable block of Sunspot for Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

In my searchable block, I have many values like this:

```
string :id
```

How can I problematically create indexed properties (here, id) on the fly? Let's say I want to create a property for the current year such as this:

```
string :<year>
```

Is this possible in Sunspot?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It seems like you're in search of `facets`.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to sort indexed documents by a per-user property (last modified time). Can facets help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass blocks instead of values.. such as

`string { (self.year + 2).to_s}`

Comment: If I do this with a user_id involved, so it is always different, which documents will get indexed with these properties?

Comment: This is not a filter on what is to be indexed, it indicates how this document will be indexed within the text engine

Comment: Is it possible to create properties to index in a loop rather than having to define each one? For instance, I'd like to create a property for each user that has accessed the document so that I can sort by it.